# How to remove the first and last letter of a string

Tags: xstring, text-manipulation

My example.

Need from the string "**$${{15}\over{4}}$$**" get the string "**${{15}\over{4}}$**".

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\f(#1){(#1)^2-5*(#1)+6}


\begin{document} 

\section{Problem}
Evaluate $f(x)=\f(x)$ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
\immediate\write18{cas "x: 1/2\string$ tex(\f(x))\string$"}
\def\SX{\input{solution}}%This file has a string "$${{15}\over{4}}$$"

\StrGobbleLeft{\SX}{1}[\SX]%It produces an error
\StrGobbleRight{\SX}{1}[\SX]%It produces an error
$f(x)=$\SX

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

With your code, `\SX` expands to `\input{solution}`, not to the contents of the file.

With `catchfile` it should work; you can even ignore the `$` signs:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\f(#1){(#1)^2-5*(#1)+6}


\begin{document}

\section{Problem}
Evaluate $f(x)=\f(x)$ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
\immediate\write18{cas "x: 1/2\string$ tex(\f(x))\string$"}

%% Read the solution file, ignoring $
\CatchFileDef\SX{solution}{\catcode`\$=9 }

$f(x)=\SX$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want fuller control and use `xstring`, then you have to use the `\expandarg` mode, not the default `\fullexpandarg`, because `\over` is not the (unexpandable) primitive any more when `amsmath` is loaded.

```
% catch the contents of solution.tex, removing the trailing space
\CatchFileDef\SX{solution}{\endlinechar=-1 }
\expandarg
\StrGobbleLeft{\SX}{2}[\SX]
\StrGobbleRight{\SX}{2}[\SX]
```

I'd remove all the `$` signs, because $f(x)=$$$ is incorrect as far as spacing is concerned.

Comment: This is basically what I was about to post.  But, I was wondering how to get `\StrGobbleRight` to work.  I thought changing catcodes for `$` to `11` would do the trick, but I still get errors.

Comment: @A.Ellett I added the reason: `\over` expands to something unwanted, when `\fullexpandarg` is in force.